# Concatenate characters for the name of a struct in Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct, string-concatenation

I want program a struct in Matlab for saving some parameters.

The struct's name has to change every iteration in a loop, thus in each iteration I make a new struct. Therefore I want something like this:

```
index={'01','02','03'};

letter={'aa','bb','cc'};

names={'Peter','John','Michael'};

for(i=1:numel(index)){

    ......

    strcat(str, index{i}, letter{i})(i).name = names{i};

}
```

Then, when the loop has finished I have 3 structs with the next names:

```
- str01aa{

  name = 'Peter'

}
- str02bb{

  name = 'John'

}
- str03cc{

  name = 'Michael'

}
```

My problem is that the `strcat` function with the bracket `(i)` is not good defined, and the structs are not created.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use cells to store these structs ?

Comment: This is a simple example that I want make...I need save some 'name' variables in a same struct

Comment: please post the exact problem, anyways you can try `eval` command , it is not recommended by many but I can't say anything else unless I look at the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat(str, index{i}, letter{i})(i).name` isn't a valid operation, because strcat returns a sting object, which can't possess fields. You need to make that string into a variable name using `genvarname` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html)), like so:

```
index={'01','02','03'};

letter={'aa','bb','cc'};

names={'Peter','John','Michael'};

for(i = 1:numel(index))
{

    ......

    genvarname(strcat('str', index{i}, letter{i}))(i).name = names{i};

}
```

Note that I changed `str` to `'str'` for consistency with your example. As a general rule, dynamically constructed variable names are bad practice because they make debugging a nightmare.

Let me make a suggestion; instead of having a bunch of structs with different, seemingly arbitrary names, why not try something like this:

```
index={'01','02','03'};

letter={'aa','bb','cc'};

names={'Peter','John','Michael'};

for(i = 1:numel(index))
{

    ......
    yourStruct(i).id = strcat('str', index{i}, letter{i});
    yourStruct(i).name = names{i};

}
```

Either way, good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Fletch !! The 'genvarname()' function is that I was looking for. XD